# Difference between Offsite Only and Local Only

Tags: fonts, web-fonts

I am using the website [Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/).

At the right side, there are three options in FONT FILTER -> DOWNLOADS. They are **Show All**, **Offsite Only** and **Local Only**.

I am kind of confused the difference between **Offsite Only** and **Local Only**. And I didn't find any information in the [Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/faq).

Can someone explain for me a little bit? Thanks

Comment: You'd be way better off contacting FontSquirrel on this one. Good luck!

Comment: @Vincent yeah, I did. I asked them first, but I wait a long time, even now I still haven't got response from them. So I asked here. And I got immediate response. Ha I think that's is charm of Stack Overflow. And more people can benefit from this question too I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Font Squirrel lists fonts that it hosts itself (**Local**) and fonts only available for download from external sites (**Offsite**).

You can use the filter you describe to view only fonts hosted by Font Squirrel, only fonts available for download from an external site or all fonts.

If you are viewing all fonts you can see if a font is only available for download from an external site by the download button, which will have "(OFFSITE)" in the buttons text.